# How to provide Credentials in http Proxy in Dotnetbrowser?

Tags: c#, http-proxy, dotnetbrowser, proxy-authentication

I'm working in [Dotnetbrowser](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/) using proxy without credentials. But i need to provide username and password in proxy. I'm implementing the [code](https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/gs/authentication.html) in my constructor. This is my working code

```
        string proxyRules = String.Format("http={0}:{1};https={0}:{1};ftp={0}:{1};socks={0}:{1}", hostName, port);

        string exceptions = "<local>";  // bypass proxy server for local web pages 

        engine.Proxy.Settings = new CustomProxySettings(proxyRules, exceptions);
```

i have found the code but couldn't implement it as code is not complete

```
network.AuthenticateHandler = new Handler<AuthenticateParameters, AuthenticateResponse>(p =>
AuthenticateResponse.Continue("<username>", "<password>"));
```

The documentation is not complete when i paste this code in my class it gives exception

```
The name 'network' does not exists in current context
```

Please provide any example code or link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to incomplete documentation i faced this problem the complete code is below:

```
engine.Network.AuthenticateHandler = new Handler<AuthenticateParameters, AuthenticateResponse>(p => AuthenticateResponse.Continue(userName, password));
```